# How can I bind the dynamic HTML inject to inner div using knockout?

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I want to bind the dynamic HTML with knockout.
here I  attached two images for references.

in first Image I am going to data-bind with knockout.
there is json object coming from the asp.net webservice Json format. after that When I click on the '+' icon then I am added html template inject after the '+' item div, and then bind that data with new json request.

first, I bind the ko.Applybindigs() with whole data list with one Viewmodel and same view model not working for newly injected Html elements..

On ready evennt I doing binding.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var ViewModel = function () {            
            var self = this;
             self.result = ko.observableArray('');
             self.newresult = ko.observableArray('');
         };
         var vmLab = new ViewModel();
         ko.applyBindings(vmLab);
});
```

after new HTML elements injecting on '+' icon click event. then trying to add array of json objects in "newresult" observalbe array.. but it getting error. 
"Error You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"

How I can achieve this by knockout .. some Html added from the jquery and bind same view model.. 
please suggest me or give alternate solution.

[image: Bind data-list]

[image: opened the data-list item]

Comment: can you post some sample data on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @raheelshan http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/po8cq1kx/

Comment: what does fiddle display? i see only two checkboxes with no label and functionality?

Comment: @raheelshan I tried but template not binding with json reponse. I tried to ko.binding but no record binding. please help me. I declared variable with json reponse..

Comment: use this one, I format the json reponse..  refer then jsonreponse variable, I need to bind this, and I also added comment "html loaded by clicking" like this in it..  http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/po8cq1kx/2/

Comment: @raheelshan http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/po8cq1kx/4/this is updated the fiddle I have been updated as per below reply of joec its working root level binding. I have update that fiddle and try to make set inner HTML div by clicking the hyperlink items.. currently Inner HTML of div not setting and then I want to bind that content..  you can check my json reponse from http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to view formatted json response.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variable inside your view model before using it in the foreach binding.
Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/po8cq1kx/3/

```
var ViewModel = function () {            
    this.result = ko.observableArray([]);              
};

var vmLab = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vmLab);

vmLab.result(updatedData);
```

Comment: No. It can be data pulled from the server. In this case, updatedData = JSON.parse(jsonResponse).planmasterdetails;

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with inner HTML dynamic binding. can you please help to load Html content by clicking the link and set to inner Div and bind it by same Ko View Model. http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekbhalani/po8cq1kx/4/